# Why doesn't theme inherit button style

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes

I am having a problems with my Transparent style inheriting the button style from the parent style (AppTheme). The button has a different style in the TransparentActivity theme.

Here are my styles, with a few items removed for simplicity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/_AppTheme"/>

<style name="_AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    ...
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="TransparentActivity" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/Trans60</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: `<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>` but where is the style named **ButtonAppTheme**?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay`

So change :

```
<style name="TransparentActivity" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/Trans60</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

To

```
<style name="TransparentActivity" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I found the solution. I had another style defined in another "values-v11" folder which was being applied and which I had not applied the button style to. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ahhhh.  Glad you got it! :)